# estimating on battery life 19.04

Tags: updates, battery, 19.04

after updating my Ubuntu Os from 18.10 to 19.04
i got a question mark '?' on battery icon 
it don't give any information about battery percentage life, i tried to check system parameter but still ever have an answer about it
need help how to solve it ?

Comment: It probably needs a full recharge and load to estimate it.

Comment: i tried to recharge it for full but always the same issue

Answer (score 0):

install tlp using these instructions:

https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html

(There is a ppa with the latest version)
then from a terminal run:

```
sudo tlp-stat
```

Amongst all the output, there are diagnostics that may give you some hints to the problem.

What is your hardware, by the way.